# IONIC 3 - HTML bug only on device

Tags: html, debugging, ionic-framework, ionic3

I got a bug on my html that shown only on devices, only iOS, not Android, browser or xCode emulator.
A button, "menuToggle" of my ionic-header seems to be cutted in half, even after many try to change css attributes, z-index etc.

I suppose it's an ios class problem, but haven't found any way to reproduce it and my css try has failed, so i'am kinda stuck.
Any tips on how can i debug it are appreciated.

```
<ion-header lightBlue-background>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle="left">
      <img src="assets/icon/homeBurger.png">
    </button>
    <img src="assets/img/img.png">
    <button ion-button icon-only>
      <img src="assets/icon/homeRefresh.png">
    </button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i randomely fixed it with "display:block !important".

Not really happy tho